# Buttons and encoder debouncing

Tags: encoder, button, debounce

I'm trying to figure out the way of debouncing encoders and tact buttons with Schmidt triggers, but I'm confused with 2 existing schematics:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f19RoA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Which of those two options are right? 
Values are shown for 5.0V inputs level, would the be the same for 3.3V?
Or for 3.3V I should use another Schmidt trigger IC (not 7414)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Encoders should not need debouncing. Tact switches are often debounced in firmware. Are you sure you need to add a logic gate for debounce?

Comment: @mkeith that "gate" is just for illustrating the presence of Schmidt trigger ( I didn't find the proper symbol in CircuitLab service).

Comment: @mkeith Yeah, some encoders need debouncing. This one, for example, when turned fast: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/TW-700198.pdf

Comment: Option 1. (Don't use option 2.) You can always use the "very boutique" MC14490 part. Gives you 6 fancy debouncers in one IC package. PRICEY!

Comment: I include the Schmidt trigger as a type of logic gate. I still suggest you debounce your button in firmware. That is the normal way to do it. I can't even remember the last time I saw external debounce hardware on a button connected to a micro-controller in a mass-produced product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is the better option. Notice that the second circuit does not provide the output gate with the intended 0 V ground when the switch is closed. It is supplied a low level voltage through a voltage divider.

However, when the switch is closed in the first circuit, the gate's input is pulled down to ground, but slowly- as the cap discharges. This is what you want.

**Edit** also read all the comments. I agree with mkeith that, if this is for a microcontroller project, consider denouncing in firmware.

And jonk is right (as he often is) that there may be better, prepackaged, options depending on your needs.

**Edit**: 3.3 V will work fine with a 7414, provided you supply the IC with 5 V nominal on the VCC pin to power the chip. The resistors are up to you.  The values of the resistors and capacitor affects the capacitor's charge/discharge time. Higher values provide more denouncing, but increase the wait time allowed between subsequent triggers. You might also want to add a voltage follower as an output stage.

For Example:
[image: Example circuit]

and...

Regarding your 7414 question in the comments:
[image: 7414 Datasheet]

Comment: Thanks for answer. But what about resistor values? Would the be the same for 3.3V signal level input? Or for 3.3V the 7414 will not work?

Comment: See addition to the answer

Comment: Well. Now it confuses me even more. If I understand the 7414 datasheet properly, it can give the output signal 0 or Vcc. If I'll do as you've described: "7414, provided you supply the IC with 5 V nominal on the VCC pin to power the chip", the 7414 output will be still 5.0V level (even if it will understand the  3.3V input as logic 1). What I wanted - attaching the output to STM32F103****, that has 3.3V signal level. Maybe, the proper question(s) is: "Will this circuit run with 3.3V input level? Could it use the 3.3V as supply? Could it produce the 3.3V level output?"

Comment: No, from the datasheet it looks like the supply voltage is 5 V nominal, and V_OH is 3.3 V.

Comment: see edit. We're getting off topic though. I would advise you click Accept Answer, and post a new question if you need advice on using the chip.